# LDAPCONN (INACTIVE): How can I successfully evaluate the cause of ldapconn inactive error?

Tags: ibm-mq, openldap

LDAP server cridentials are configured correctly, however I am unable to get to the figure out why LDAPCONN is INACTIVE. The logs are not showing the issue.

```
DEFINE AUTHINFO(USE.LDAP) AUTHTYPE(IDPWLDAP) CONNAME('127.0.0.1(389)') LDAPUSER('cn=admin,dc=organisation,dc=co,dc=za') LDAPPWD('admin') SHORTUSR('mqm') REPLACE
AMQ8563: IBM MQ authentication information object created.

ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH(USE.LDAP)
AMQ8005: IBM MQ queue manager changed

REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)
AMQ8560: IBM MQ security cache refreshed.

DISPLAY QMSTATUS LDAPCONN
AMQ8705: Display Queue Manager Status Details.
   QMNAME(TEST)                            STATUS(RUNNING)
   LDAPCONN(INACTIVE)
```

When executing DISPLAY QMSTATUS LDAPCONN. I want to be able to see LDAPCONN(ACTIVE).

Comment: `LDAPCONN(INACTIVE)` means "The queue manager is not configured to use an LDAP server or has not yet made a connection to the LDAP server."  The fact that it is not showing `LDAPCONN(ERROR)` is a good sign.  Have you attempted to authenicate a user to the queue manager with CONNAUTH?  I am fairly certain that the queue manager does not connect to LDAP until you first try to authenticate a user.  I do not agree with @frabar, I think your LDAPUSER looks fine, the KC describes this as "The Distinguished Name of the user who is accessing the LDAP server."

Comment: What does look off to me is the `SHORTUSR` field which the name of the field in LDAP that contains the username that is 12 characters or less.  In Active Directory this is normally as @frabar pointed out is the field `sAMAccountName`, but as you have tagged this as [openldap] yours may be different.  Also note that I believe you need to set the `BASEDNU` which is described as the "In order to be able to find the short user name attribute (see SHORTUSR ) this parameter must be set with the base DN to search for users within the LDAP server."

Comment: Also you are not setting `AUTHORMD` so by default it will be set to `OS`, this means that the LDAP SHORTUSR field must resolve to a local OS user for OAM checking.  So based on the above I think once you attempt to authenticate a user via CONNAUTH you will see the status either be `CONNECTED` or `ERROR`.  It may connect fine, but due to the other issue above it likely will not work.

Comment: Thulasizwe do you have any updates on your issue?  Did the comments above help you, if they did I would like to provide them as a answer for you.  If the answer from frabar helped them please accept that answer.

Comment: @JoshMc thanks. Managed to get LDAPCONN active. I realised it is also important to do typo checks when defining LDAP AUTHINFO.

Comment: So what was the exact issue and what did you do to solve it?  If it was a typo please us know what is what, it may be helpful to people in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work with Thulasizwe and we found the problem.

We are using an IBM MQ docker container to do local testing for our LDAP solution that we are busy with. The issue was caused by an environment variable which is passed to the docker container, basically disabling the IBM OAM (Object Authority Manager) of the MQ server. This has the result of still authenticating against the LDAP server, but disabling object authority checking of the MQ server.

With the OAM switched off, the Queue Manager reports the LDAPCONN as INACTIVE (although authentication is still done against the LDAP server).

After removing the environment variable which causes the OAM to be disabled, the authority manager switched on and the LDAPCONN reported CONNECTED.

#### LDAP Configuration in IBM MQ server

```
DEFINE AUTHINFO(USE.LDAP) AUTHTYPE(IDPWLDAP) + 
CONNAME('127.0.0.1(10389)') + 
LDAPUSER('uid=adminuser,cn=users,ou=organisation,dc=sa') LDAPPWD('password') + 
BASEDNG('cn=groups,ou=organisation,dc=sa') + 
BASEDNU('cn=users,ou=organisation,dc=sa') + 
CLASSUSR('inetOrgPerson') CLASSGRP('groupOfUniqueNames') +
FINDGRP('uniqueMember') GRPFIELD('cn') USRFIELD('uid') + 
SHORTUSR('uid') AUTHORMD(SEARCHGRP) +
DESCR('LDAP authentication module.') +
REPLACE
```

#### Environment variable which caused the issue

In the creation of the docker container (look in your Dockerfile) there was an environment variable set:

```
FROM ibmcom/mq:latest
...

ENV MQSNOAUT="YES"

...
```

The environment variable **MQSNOAUT** tells the queue manager to disable the OAM when the manager is created.

To read more about the MQ environment variables here: [(IBM Knowledge center, SSFKSJ_9.0.0)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.con.doc/q082720_.htm).

We used the docker container at: [https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/mq](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/mq/)

After removing the setting, everything worked as expected.

Thank you all for the responses. Hope this answer helps someone else in future.

#### Afterthought

But, to answer the main question about if IBM indicates ***this specific INACTIVE issue*** in the logs, the answer is no. I suppose that the status of INACTIVE in our case was correct since it indicated that the OAM is not active. But, in our case LDAP connectivity is not completely inactive since the MQ server still used the LDAP server for the authentication of the user (thus it did connect!). Credential checking of the user (login) against the LDAP server was done successfully even with the status showing INACTIVE. So the INACTIVE indicator in our case is a bit confusing for me.

I.r.o the indicator otherwise, it will have a state of INACTIVE, CONNECTED or ERROR. If everything is fine, the status will be CONNECTED, else it will have a status of ERROR in which case you can check the logs under the /var/mqm/qmgr/QMGR/error for more information about the issue.

Comment: Have you co-worker accept this answer as it was the cause of the problem.

Comment: Hi Josh, yes he did. Thank you for your contribution, since the fact that it was not in an ERROR state was a good sign!

Answer (score 0):

The errors for the queue manager should be in the below path.

Paths below based on

```
  UNIX and Linux systems    ==> /var/mqm/qmgrs/qmname/errors
  Windows systems ==>   MQ_INSTALLATION_PATH\QMGRS\qmname\ERRORS\AMQERR01.LOG
```

Please ensure you are able to login to LDAP server using the credentials. Your user name LDAPUSER looks incorrect to me. You should first trying logging into your LDAP using the username password. If it works then configure it using MQ runmqsc. Below is a sample command

```
 DEFINE AUTHINFO('USE.LDAP') +
  AUTHTYPE(IDPWLDAP) +
  ADOPTCTX(YES) +
  CONNAME('127.0.0.1(389)') +
  CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL) +
 CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL) +
  CLASSGRP('GROUP') +
 CLASSUSR('USER') +
 BASEDNG('put your base dng') +
 BASEDNU('put your base dnu') +
 FINDGRP('member') +
 LDAPUSER('admin') +
 LDAPPWD('password') +
 SECCOMM(NO) +
 SHORTUSR('sAMAccountName') +
USRFIELD('sAMAccountName') +
 GRPFIELD('sAMAccountName') +
 AUTHORMD(SEARCHGRP) +
  REPLACE
```